# creating tables in MS Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

What are the codes to create a table in MS Word?

I've used the record function for macro to see how it is written and i have no idea how to interpret this.

and can you not draw tables while recording a macro? It greys out the "draw table" function.

I need to make a talbe that has some merged cells within the table - it would be easier if i can draw the table and record using macro but it seems like i can't do that...

[image: table]

I've used the draw function to draw the follow table but i can't record it.

HELP?!

Comment: Why not just copy that table from a template document?

Comment: what do you mean template document? the thing is, i want to creat the exact same table everytime i click the macro. because i need to create the same table multiple times

Comment: I mean just create that table in a word doc, then in your macro load up the doc and copy the table to wherever you need it.

Comment: but everytime i run the macro, it doesn't paste the table but rather it pastes the page? i'm not sure if that makes sense, when i try to copy the table while recording a macro, i can't drag and highlight to copy the table. so I did alt+A to copy the table and pasted it. but everytime i run the macro it would paste the page when i only want to paste the table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
Sub Tester()


    Dim x, w, c

    ThisDocument.Tables(1).Delete

    ThisDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=7, NumColumns:=1, _
                          DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
                          AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed

    With ThisDocument.Tables(1)

        .Rows.Height = 70
        w = .Rows(1).Cells(1).Width

        .Rows(1).Cells(1).Split 1, 7
        .Rows(1).Cells(1).Width = w / 2
        For x = 2 To 7
            .Rows(1).Cells(x).Width = (w / 2) / 6
        Next x

        .Rows(5).Height = 15
        .Rows(7).Height = 15

        .Rows(7).Cells(1).Split 1, 7

        .Rows(6).Cells(1).Split 1, 4
        .Rows(6).Cells(2).Split 2, 1

        'Once you merge cells it gets difficult to use .Rows, but
        '  you can still address individual cells. Use the loop below to
        '  find out which one you need to operate on...
        x = 1
        For Each c In .Range.Cells
            c.Range.Text = x
            x = x + 1
        Next c

        .Range.Cells(16).Split 1, 4
        'you can figure out setting the exact required widths...
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim,Sorry for the late response. I've tried your code but it gives me an error that collection does not exist. how do i fix that? I'm trying to interpret the code you provide but it's quite hard to understand what you did since i'm not very familiar with vba (ex. i don't understand how that code made tables...using x=x+1) i want to add texts and fill the table with colors but i'm not sure how to do that as well.

Comment: Comment out the line `ThisDocument.Tables(1).Delete` - that was from my testing.

Comment: Hi Tim I get an error that specified range is not from the correct document. how do i fix that?

Comment: sorry i got it. but how do i insert texts to the individual cell? and how do i make it so that whenever i run the macro it would create a new table in a different page?

Comment: How to add text to a cell is right there in my answer. I don't know how you'd add a new table in a different page.

Answer (score 4):

the basic command for making a table is

```
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=4, NumColumns:= 3
```

and to split/merge cells:

```
Selection.Cells.Split NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=2
Selection.Cells.Merge
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the table and then save it as an autotext (select table - ALT+F3 - name of the autotext).  Then when you need the table in a document, just type the name you gave it and press F3.