# Error 13 (type mismatch) using array containing named ranges of varying sizes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

**Background:**

Planning to define locations in a Word document with pre-defined strings, and use Excel to import the data to those locations.  This includes replacement of a pre-defined string with another string (cell value), as well as replacing a pre-defined string with a table (named range in Excel, varying column/row counts).

I was planning to use arrays to do the replaces.

---

**Issue:**

I am attempting to save locations in an array (quite improperly) named brr, where my array consists of locations in the spreadsheet, inclusive of single cells and named range tables.

I get an error when attempting to use brr for the tables (named ranges) in the loop: *run-time error 13, type mismatch*.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to fix brr to be inclusive of tables, and how?

*Or*, is there a more appropriate way of performing this replace?

---

**Code in Question:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Replace_from_Excel_to_Word()
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant, brr As Variant, WApp As Object, loc As String
    arr = Array("[1]", "[2]", "[3]", "[4]", "[5]", "[Table1]", "[Table2]", "[Table3]")
    brr = Array(Sheets("Profile").Cells(1, 2).Value, Sheets("Profile").Cells(2, 2).Value, Sheets("Profile").Cells(3, 2).Value, Sheets("Profile").Cells(4, 2).Value, Sheets("Profile").Cells(5, 2).Value, Sheets("Table1").Range("Table1").Value, Sheets("Table2").Range("Table2").Value, Sheets("Table3").Range("Table3").Value)
    loc = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Other_Projects\MWR_SPz\Template.docx"
    Set WApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WApp.Documents.Open (loc)
    WApp.Visible = True
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        With WApp.ActiveDocument
            With .Content.Find
                .Execute FindText:=arr(i), ReplaceWith:=brr(i), Replace:=1
            End With
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It's possible ReplaceWith expects a string.  What are the values of arr(i) and brr(i) when it fails?

Comment: This is rather basic, but have you checked there are no errors in the cells containing the values of `brr`? Does the code work if you replace the values of `brr` with dummy values you don't retrieve from the document?

Comment: @TimWilliams the errors start when we move to the named ranges (tables) in brr, arr value Table1.  As the array expects a string, is there a way to have a dynamic range via an array, or should i just be calling the named ranges directly?

Comment: The value of a multi-cell range is a 2-d array, so you can't use this approach to create a table in the document - you will need to create those the "long" way (ie step-by-step)

Comment: You could use something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/exporting-a-range-to-a-table-in-a-word-document

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the reference; i will give that a try.

Comment: @TimWilliams if you can post your 2-d array comment as an answer, i will accept it, so this doesn't linger open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a multi-cell range is a 2-d array, so you can't use this approach to create a table in the document - you will need to create those the "long" way (ie step-by-step)

Possibly useful:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/exporting-a-range-to-a-table-in-a-word-document
- [creating tables in MS Word using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366136/creating-tables-in-ms-word-using-vba/13368147#13368147)

... and other Q here on SO